# Print a header in python

Tags: python, header, cgi

Is there a python equivalent to this in perl?

```
use CGI;
my $IN = new CGI;
print $IN->header();
# $IN->header(-type=>'image/gif');
```

I see that this will print a header along with the ENV information:

```
import cgi
cgi.test()
```

Obviously I don't need the ENV information when not debugging. Otherwise do I need to type the `print "Content-type: text/html"` or `print "Content-type: image/gif"` everytime or is there a module already written that is similar?